# Best practice for testing a django project

Tags: django, testing, pytest, pytest-django

I have a django project with 3 apps. Now, I want to test my project. So I was in dilemma that what should be the best practice for testing a Django project with pytest?

Which approach is preferable ?

Approach 1 :

```
└── app_name
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── test_forms.py
        ├── test_models.py
        └── test_views.py
```

Approach 2 :

```
└── app_name
    └── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── unit_tests
           ├── __init__.py
           ├── test_views.py
           ├── test_models.py
           ├── test_forms.py
        ├── integration_tests
           ├── __init__.py
           ├── test_views.py
           ├── test_models.py
           ├── test_forms.py
        ├── functional_tests
           ├── __init__.py
           ├── test_views.py
           ├── test_models.py
           ├── test_forms.py
```

**Note : We are using pytest here.**

What I am expecting is which approach should be followed while testing a django project